# How to export acquisition channel from GA?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I use Google Analytics to track an acquisition channel for android and ios users. How can I export a list of users with user's ID and acquisition channel? Programmatically via Query explorer or manual exporting alternatives are welcome.
I can export a list of users without acquisition channel field in User Explorer. But this field is presented on detailed page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one of the possible ways is

1. Create a custom dimension in GA to store User ID. User ID might be your own generated key of user.

2. Sending this User ID to GA from your mobile app.

3. Build a query to selecting needed information in GA reporting.


More information here https://www.mugo.ca/Blog/Tracking-individual-users-in-Google-Analytics